# SQL RIGHT JOIN query to include all children?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have tables `A`, `B`, and a `A_B_MEMBERS` table that links `A` and `B`. `A` can have multiple `B`, and `B` can have multiple `A`. Consider the following concrete table schemas:

```sql
CREATE TABLE A (
    a_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    data TEXT
)

CREATE TABLE B (
    b_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    data TEXT
)

CREATE TABLE A_B_MEMBERS (
    a_id NOT NULL REFERENCES A(a_id),
    b_id NOT NULL REFERENCES B(b_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (a_id, b_id)
)
```

Given a `b_id`, I want to query for all `A`s that have this `b_id` but also return all other `b_id`s this `A` contains. So consider the following example:

```
a_id | data
-----+-----
1    | "hi"
2    | "hello"
3    | "cao"

b_id | data
-----+-----
1    | "people"
2    | "world"
3    | "foo"

a_id | b_id
-----+-----
1    | 1
1    | 2
1    | 3
2    | 1
2    | 2
3    | 3
```

So `a_id=1` has `b_id={1,2,3}`, `a_id=2` has `b_id={1,2}`, `a_id=3` has `b_id={3}`.

Given, say `b_id=2`, the return should be:

```
a_id |   data   | b_id_arr
-----+----------+---------
1    | "hi"     | {1,2,3}
2    | "hello"  | {1,2}
```

I'm unable to do this through table joins and is forced to do two separate queries. I've tried the following:

```sql
SELECT
a.*,
ARRAY_AGG(abm.b_id) b_id_arr
FROM A a
RIGHT JOIN A_B_MEMBERS abm
ON a.a_id = abm.a_id
AND abm.b_id = 2
GROUP by a.a_id;
```

But this doesn't seem to give me what I'd want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `left join` -- the logic is just easier to follow:  keep all rows in the first table you see in the `from` clause.

That said, you don't seem to need an outer join.  You simply want to groups that have a "2".  That suggests a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT a.*, ARRAY_AGG(abm.b_id)
FROM A a JOIN
     A_B_MEMBERS abm
     ON a.a_id = abm.a_id
GROUP by a.a_id
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE abm.b_id = 2) > 0
```

Comment: You said to use `left join`? but the example is an `inner join`.

Comment: @thestateofmay . . . If you are going to use an outer join, use `left join`.  After going through the logic, though, it appears that an inner join is sufficient.